# Cannot connect to SQL Server from local machine to virtual machine hosted on another PC

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machines, virtualbox, sql-server-express

I have installed SQL Server Express 2008 R2 on a Windows 7 virtual machine - this virtual machine is hosted on another PC on our network. I would like to connect to the server using SQL Server Management Studio from my local machine but I get the following error:

[image]

First thing I tried was to be able to ping my virtual machine and I was able to do so by changing some settings on my Virtual Box and also firewall settings for my virtual machine. I've also made sure that the `sa` account is enabled which I will be using to access the server. From here on I am stuck.

Comment: Ping isn't a SQL Server connectivity testing tool. Have you made sure that TCP/IP and or Named Pipes are enabled for SQL Server?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes I did on the sql configuration manager

Comment: Do you installed SQL as named instance or default ?

Comment: @tasmanian_devil it is a named instance

Answer (score 1):

Try open up a connection to your sql instance via telnet.

```
telnet 192.168.2.110 <port it's listening on>
```

(See your SQL Server Configuration Manager to see which one it is).

Is SQL Browser running? Try connecting using `192.168.2.110,port`in SSMS.

Comment: Thanks, man! 192.168.2.110,port works for me!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Express by default doesn't listen to TCP. You need to turn on "TCP/IP" in SQL Server Configuration Manager → Network Configuration → Protocols.

Additionally, if the Express instance is not the default one you'll need to have the SQL Browser service running. Configure firewall accordingly.